# -[NSNull objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c

I got an exception that says:

`-[NSNull objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Is it saying I am trying to access an `NSNull` object with a key?
Any idea what causes this and how to fix it or debug further?

Comment: Should be easy enough to find.  Where are you subscripting?

Comment: It looks like you have a NSNull where you were expecting something else. Some code would help people help you figure this out.

Comment: The way to fix it is to not attempt objectForKeyedSubscript on an NSNull object.  (I'm betting you're handling some JSON data and aren't prepared for a NULL value.)

Comment: (And apparently objectForKeyedSubscript is what the new `array[x]` notation translates into.)

Comment: @HotLicks `NSDictionary`, `NSArray` has `- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx`.

Comment: @MikeD - "This method is identical to objectAtIndex:."  Apparently it was added to support the new `[]` notation (though the need is far from obvious).  Not something that a programmer would intentionally use directly since it's simply more characters to type (and get wrong).

Comment: @HotLicks Agreed. The method mentioned in the question refers to `NSDictionary`. The literal syntax calls these new methods, depending on the type in question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way to fix it is to not attempt objectForKeyedSubscript on an NSNull object. (I'm betting you're handling some JSON data and aren't prepared for a NULL value.)

(And apparently objectForKeyedSubscript is what the new array[x] notation translates into.)

(Note that you can test for NSNull by simply comparing with `==` to `[NSNull null]`, since there's one and only one NSNull object in the app.)

Comment: Would accessing a dictionary with a key that is invalid throw this exception?

Comment: @Boon No. That would return `nil`, which very different from `NSNull`.

Comment: @Boon - As Mike D says, using an invalid key on a dictionary will just return a nil -- no exception.  An invalid index on an array will throw an exception, but it's an NSRangeException, not "unrecognized selector".  Note, though, that you'd get the "unrecognized selector" if you attempted to "index" an NSString, or an NSView or some other non-array/dictionary object -- it's a generic error meaning that the specified class does not support the specified method.

Answer (score 2):

What ever value you are storing, despite what the editor tells you, at run time you are storing an `NSNull`, and later on trying to call `objectForKeyedSubscript`. I am guessing this happening on what is expected to be an `NSDictionary`. Some thing like:

`NSString *str = dict[@"SomeKey"]`

Either a piece of code beforehand is not doing its job and investigate there, or perform some validation:

```
NSDictionary *dict = ...;

if ( [dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ) {
    // handle the dictionary
}
else {
   // some kind of error, handle appropriately
}
```

I often have this kind of scenario when dealing with error messages from networking operations.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a category to NSNull to handle this in the same way you would expect a subscript call to be handled if it it were sent to nil.

```
@implementation NSNull (Additions)

- (NSObject*)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id<NSCopying>)key {
    return nil;
}

- (NSObject*)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx {
    return nil;
}

@end
```

A simple way to test is like this:

```
id n = [NSNull null];
n[@""];
n[0];
```

With this category, this test should be handled successfully/softly.