# Crash when assigning null to NSString from JSON data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring

I am experiencing a crash that I have narrowed down to this line of code but I dont understand how I can avoid it.

```
NSString *variantImageUrl = variantEdge[@"node"][@"image"][@"src"];
```

If the value of src is null the app crashes with the following error message

```
    2017-11-21 17:23:27.023988+0800 NWMPos[3218:2124447] -[NSNull objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b2a01650
2017-11-21 17:23:27.026199+0800 NWMPos[3218:2124447] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b2a01650'
```

As long as the value of src is a proper string it works fine

But I cannot check the value for null before I assign it so how can avoid the crash?

Comment: According to the error message, it seems that `variantEdge[@"node"][@"image"]` or `variantEdge[@"node"]` is null. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237199/nsnull-objectforkeyedsubscript-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance ?

Comment: ah I see what you mean, I thought the src was null but its actually the entire key thats gone, so image itself is null, I just unsure how to test for that, I did read the link but I am still a bit confused

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839355/checking-a-null-value-in-objective-c-that-has-been-returned-from-a-json-string ? Else using the category on previous link answer should return nil for  `variantEdge[@"node"]` instead of null, and then it shouldn't crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add check for null:

```
if(![variantEdge[@"node"][@"image"][@"src"] isEqual:[NSNull null]])
{
    NSString *variantImageUrl = variantEdge[@"node"][@"image"][@"src"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clumsy as hell, but

```
NSDictionary *dict = variantEdge;

for (NSString *key in @[@"node", @"image"]) {
   dict = dict[key];
   if (![dict isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.class]) {
      dict = nil;
      break;
   }
}

NSString *url = dict ? dict["src"] : nil;
```